# How to remove multiple files in VxWorks?

Tags: shell, command, vxworks

I have an embedded software that runs on VxWorks 7. It creates a new log file every time the hardware is reset. How can I delete these log files in one command? Since there are other files in directory, it would be great if I can specify which files to remove using its prefix?

Most of the VxWorks commands look like Linux commands but that doesn't work in this case.

Comment: What have you tried ? was there an error ?

Comment: @dash-o I have tried **rm log* and rm *.txt**. It gave syntax error.

Comment: Can you post exact error message + ls that shows the log files ?

Comment: I will post it but I will not be in the office until wednesday.

Comment: **-> rm "log*"** on kernel shell. **[vxWorks] rm log*** on command-interpreter shell.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "xdelete", unlike "rm" it takes wildcards. You can find it under usrFsLib's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Most "commands" are intended for developer's convenience, VxWorks "commands" are not strongly intended for deployed products.

You could synthesize your own command or write the underlying C functions to accomplish your goals.